# How to remove globally a package from Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, command-line-interface

I ran this command to install globally *PHPUnit*:

```
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*'
```

Now I want to uninstall globally *PHPUnit*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

To remove a globally installed package run:

```sh
composer global remove phpunit/phpunit
```

`global` command lets you to run many commands like `install`, `require` or `update` as if you were running them from the `COMPOSER_HOME` directory.

Read the related documentation here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global

`COMPOSER_HOME` depends on your system (on Linux it's `~/.composer`), see http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home for more details.

Comment: Are there any reasons composer global update would not work? I removed a package from my composer.json in .composer and ran the global update but I can still execute the program.

Comment: A `remove` command has been added to composer.  See [this PR](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/2479) and [this commit](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/e3f32a79f30e55737c6c75bcf3e688c7c5e1bd9f).

Comment: @iisisrael it doesn't work for packages installed globally and this is what this question is about. Thanks for reference though!

Comment: Composer supports global remove now. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use another way

```
cd $HOME/.config/composer
```

And in `composer.json` file remove some require positions

After all execute `composer update`
This is a long way, but more clear

Comment: I used `composer global update`

Comment: I found this config file at `~/.composer/composer.json` in brew installed composer