# Laravel Installer Version 1.3.3 and Framework 5.2 cannot be removed from my MAC

Tags: php, macos, laravel-5

Trying to install Spark Laravel 3 I realized that my current laravel installer was version 1.3.3. Laravel Spark request version 1.3.4.
several procedures were made in order to use version 1.3.4.

- update composer
- erase laravel installer from ~/.composer/vendor/bin
  etc.

no matter what I do, it seems that the installer is loaded and used from some cache. consequently an old version 1.3.3 is installed.

Running `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.3.4"` version 1.3.4 is installed. running `laravel -V` says 1.3.4 but then when I install in

> localhost/laravel

and run `laravel -V` it says 1.3.3

UPDATE//////////////////////////////////////////////////

following bagus-tesa advise i used composer global remove laravel/installer with success.

Im confused, because despite in ~/.composer/bin calling laravel -V displays 1.3.4 when I install laravel spark it always install laravel version 5.2 instead of version laravel 5.3

anyone knows if spark laravel has a place in configuration to force installing laravel 5.3 version? brgds

Comment: never tried myself, but [`composer global remove`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217477/how-to-remove-globally-a-package-from-composer) might be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install**

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.3.4"
```

**Uninstall**

```
composer global remove laravel/installer
```

`laravel` installer is just an alternative way to create `laravel` project. I have not find it so useful in my opinion.

You can do the same thing using composer:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.3.0 projectName --prefer-dist
```

If it does not work, make sure you have the minimum PHP version required for the chosen laravel version

Comment: thank you @meda, but laravel spark has its own installer. its possible to run first laravel project and then laravel spark using php artisan spark:install --force ?